# How can i use an array of threads from process in C

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system

This is my project about an airport structure. I made two process (one for each type of aircraft) and each process is making several threads (one thread is one aircraft).

Each thread run Pilot function which take structureVol (data structure) in input and do this:

- departure function (wait until critical ressources is free an take it)
- wait (simulation of the travel)
- arrival function (same thing as departure function)
- kill thread

I don't understand why the script is running without errors and return almost nothing.
After many tries (with `printf("something")`) I found that case 0 is not used by the script but typeheavy and typelight return 0.

I also found that it work when only one thread is initialized instead of an array of it.

After several hours of working I don't know the awnser.

Excuse my mistakes in english.

Thanks a lot.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutexPisteCourte = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; //Short airplane landing strip mutex
pthread_mutex_t mutexPisteLongue = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; //Long airplane landing strip mutex

#define tempsPiste 5    // Temps passé sur une piste (décoller et attérir) //Time on landing strip
#define tempsAeroport 5 // Temps max passé dans un aéroport // Time in a airport
#define tempsFrance 10  //Temps max de trajet en France // Time to travel through France
#define tempsEurope 25  //Temps max de trajet en Europe // Time to travel through Europe
#define nbAvionsLourd 5
#define nbAvionsLeger 2

//Prototypes
void attente(); // Wait function
void depart(int, int); //departure function
void arrivee(int, int); //arrival function
void affichage(int, char*); //display function
void *Pilote(void *); //Pilot function

//Structure représentant les données de vol //Structure were data are stored (id flight, type, destination and so on)
typedef struct structureVol
{
    long id;
    long type;
    long destination;
}structureVol;

                        /*----------------*/
                        /* -- Fonctions --*/
                        /*----------------*/

void depart(int i,int j) //departure function
{
    printf("Depart pris en compte"); //Test
    if (j==0)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexPisteCourte);
        attente(tempsPiste);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexPisteCourte);
    }
    if (j==1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexPisteLongue);
        attente(tempsPiste);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexPisteLongue);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Erreur sur l'attribution piste décollage");
    }
    /* TO DO
    Indiquer la piste de départ
    Indiquer l'itinéraire normalisé
    Indiquer la route à suivre jusqu'à la sortie de l'espace controlé ou le premier
    point de report
    Donner l'heure de décolage et sa limite.
    Départs réalisés dans l'ordre dans lequel les avions sont prêt à décoller
    Dernière règle peut être déroger pour avoir un maximum de départs ainsi qu'un
    retard moyen le plus faible
    */
}

void arrivee(int i,int j) //arrival function
{
    printf("Arrivée prise en compte"); //test
    if (j==0)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexPisteCourte);
        attente(tempsPiste);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexPisteCourte);
    }
    if (j==1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexPisteLongue);
        attente(tempsPiste);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexPisteLongue);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Erreur sur l'attribution piste arrivée");
    }
    /* TO DO
    Indiquer l'itinéraire normalisé ou la description de la route à suivre 
    jusqu'au point d'approche initiale ou au repère d'attente, jusqu'à un point
    significatif ou jusqu'à l'entrée du circuit d'aerodrome, indiquer l'heure
    d'approche prévue en cas d'attente ou l'estimation de la durée d'attente prévue.
    */
}


void *Pilote (void *arg) //Pilot function
{
    structureVol *donnees =(structureVol *) arg;

    /*  Depart de l'avion   */
    printf("Début du thread");
    depart(donnees->id,donnees->type);
    fprintf(stderr,"\033[91m le vol %ld de type %ld a démarer \033[0m\n",donnees->id,donnees->type);
    /*  Voyage de l'avion   */
    attente(tempsFrance); //Avion en vol vers France
    attente(tempsAeroport); //Avion en stationnement dans un autre aéroport
    attente(tempsFrance); //Avion sur le retour de France
    /*  Arrivé de l'avion   */
    arrivee(donnees->id,donnees->type);
    fprintf(stderr,"\033[91m le vol %ld de type %ld s'est bien terminé \033[0m\n",donnees->id,donnees->type);
    pthread_exit(NULL); //Fin thread

}

void attente(int i) /* Fonction permettant d'attendre un temps aléatoire entre 1 et i */ // Wait a time between i and 1 second
{
    //Initialisation du générateur de nombres aléatoire utilisant le temps système comme référence
    srand(time(NULL));
    int temps=rand()%i+1;
    printf("Attente de %d secondes \n", temps); 
    sleep(temps);
}

void affichage(int i, char* texte) //display function
{
    #define COLONNE 10
    int k, Espace;
    Espace = i*COLONNE ;
    for (k=0; k<Espace; k++)
    {
        putchar(' ');
    }
    printf("%s\n",texte);
    fflush(stdout);
}

                            /*------------*/
                            /* -- Main -- */
                            /*------------*/

int main (void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int thr = 0;
    //int nbAvionsTotal = nbAvionsLeger + nbAvionsLourd;

    structureVol *donneesVol;

    //char *s1, *s2;

    int typeheavy;
    int typelight;

    pthread_t avionlourds[nbAvionsLourd];
    pthread_t avionleger[nbAvionsLeger];

    printf("  -----  Initialisation du programme  ----- \n\n");

    affichage(1,"     -- Piste légère --  -- Piste lourde --\n");
    affichage(2,"Test 1");
    affichage(4,"Test 2");

    switch(typeheavy = fork())
    {   

        case -1:        
            printf("Erreur dans la création processus avion lourd \n");
            break;

        case 0: /* Processus type l'avion lourd */

            printf("test_");
            printf("je suis le fils");
            for (i=0; i<nbAvionsLourd; i++)
            {
                printf("test2_");
                donneesVol-> id = i;
                donneesVol->type = 1;
                donneesVol->destination = 0;

                /*   --- Creation de un thread par avion ---   */
                thr=pthread_create(&avionlourds[i], NULL, Pilote, (void *) donneesVol);
                /*  Erreur de création thread  */            

                if (thr)
                {
                    printf("Erreur sur thread %d type avion lourd \n",i);
                }
                for (i=0; i<nbAvionsLourd; i++)
                {
                    pthread_join(avionlourds[i],NULL);
                }

            }

            exit(0);

        default: /* Controleur (poursuit le programme) */

            printf("Dans le default\n");
            wait(0);
            printf("wait passé\n");

    } 
    printf("dans le main\n");
    switch(typelight = fork())
    {
        case -1:
            printf("Erreur dans la création processus avion léger \n");
            break;

        case 0: /* Processus fils type l'avion léger */
            for (i=0; i<nbAvionsLeger; i++)
            {
                donneesVol->id = i;
                donneesVol->type = 0;
                donneesVol->destination = 0;

                /*   --- Creation de un thread par avion ---   */
                thr=pthread_create(&avionleger[i], NULL, Pilote, (void*) donneesVol);
                /*  Erreur de création thread  */  
                if (thr)
                {
                    printf("Erreur sur thread %d type avion léger \n",i);
                }
                for (i=0; i<nbAvionsLeger; i++)
                {
                    pthread_join(avionleger[i],NULL);
                }
                exit(0);

            }   


        default: /* Controleur (poursuit le programme) */
            wait(0);
            printf("wait passé\n");

    }

    printf("\n  -----        Fin du programme       ----- \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is 'donnesVol' allocated?  You should allocate one per thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors in your code, the first is that you should put a break at the end of evry case (or the program fall through), the second is that `donneesVol` is unitialized, your corrected code is this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutexPisteCourte = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; //Short airplane landing strip mutex
pthread_mutex_t mutexPisteLongue = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; //Long airplane landing strip mutex

#define tempsPiste 5    // Temps passé sur une piste (décoller et attérir) //Time on landing strip
#define tempsAeroport 5 // Temps max passé dans un aéroport // Time in a airport
#define tempsFrance 10  //Temps max de trajet en France // Time to travel through France
#define tempsEurope 25  //Temps max de trajet en Europe // Time to travel through Europe
#define nbAvionsLourd 5
#define nbAvionsLeger 2
#define BUF_SIZE 100

//Prototypes
void attente(); // Wait function
void depart(int, int); //departure function
void arrivee(int, int); //arrival function
void affichage(int, char*); //display function
void *Pilote(void *); //Pilot function

//Structure représentant les données de vol //Structure were data are stored (id flight, type, destination and so on)
typedef struct structureVol
{
    long id;
    long type;
    long destination;
}structureVol;

                        /*----------------*/
                        /* -- Fonctions --*/
                        /*----------------*/

void depart(int i,int j) //departure function
{
    printf("Depart pris en compte"); //Test
    if (j==0)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexPisteCourte);
        attente(tempsPiste);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexPisteCourte);
    }
    if (j==1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexPisteLongue);
        attente(tempsPiste);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexPisteLongue);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Erreur sur l'attribution piste décollage");
    }
    /* TO DO
    Indiquer la piste de départ
    Indiquer l'itinéraire normalisé
    Indiquer la route à suivre jusqu'à la sortie de l'espace controlé ou le premier
    point de report
    Donner l'heure de décolage et sa limite.
    Départs réalisés dans l'ordre dans lequel les avions sont prêt à décoller
    Dernière règle peut être déroger pour avoir un maximum de départs ainsi qu'un
    retard moyen le plus faible
    */
}

void arrivee(int i,int j) //arrival function
{
    printf("Arrivée prise en compte"); //test
    if (j==0)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexPisteCourte);
        attente(tempsPiste);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexPisteCourte);
    }
    if (j==1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexPisteLongue);
        attente(tempsPiste);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexPisteLongue);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Erreur sur l'attribution piste arrivée");
    }
    /* TO DO
    Indiquer l'itinéraire normalisé ou la description de la route à suivre
    jusqu'au point d'approche initiale ou au repère d'attente, jusqu'à un point
    significatif ou jusqu'à l'entrée du circuit d'aerodrome, indiquer l'heure
    d'approche prévue en cas d'attente ou l'estimation de la durée d'attente prévue.
    */
}


void *Pilote (void *arg) //Pilot function
{
    structureVol *donnees =(structureVol *) arg;

    /*  Depart de l'avion   */
    printf("Début du thread");
    depart(donnees->id,donnees->type);
    fprintf(stderr,"\033[91m le vol %ld de type %ld a démarer \033[0m\n",donnees->id,donnees->type);
    /*  Voyage de l'avion   */
    attente(tempsFrance); //Avion en vol vers France
    attente(tempsAeroport); //Avion en stationnement dans un autre aéroport
    attente(tempsFrance); //Avion sur le retour de France
    /*  Arrivé de l'avion   */
    arrivee(donnees->id,donnees->type);
    fprintf(stderr,"\033[91m le vol %ld de type %ld s'est bien terminé \033[0m\n",donnees->id,donnees->type);
    pthread_exit(NULL); //Fin thread

}

void attente(int i) /* Fonction permettant d'attendre un temps aléatoire entre 1 et i */ // Wait a time between i and 1 second
{
    //Initialisation du générateur de nombres aléatoire utilisant le temps système comme référence
    srand(time(NULL));
    int temps=rand()%i+1;
    printf("Attente de %d secondes \n", temps);
    sleep(temps);
}

void affichage(int i, char* texte) //display function
{
    #define COLONNE 10
    int k, Espace;
    Espace = i*COLONNE ;
    for (k=0; k<Espace; k++)
    {
        putchar(' ');
    }
    printf("%s\n",texte);
    fflush(stdout);
}

                            /*------------*/
                            /* -- Main -- */
                            /*------------*/

int main (void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int thr = 0;
    //int nbAvionsTotal = nbAvionsLeger + nbAvionsLourd;

    structureVol donneesVol[BUF_SIZE];

    //char *s1, *s2;

    int typeheavy;
    int typelight;

    pthread_t avionlourds[nbAvionsLourd];
    pthread_t avionleger[nbAvionsLeger];

    printf("  -----  Initialisation du programme  ----- \n\n");

    affichage(1,"     -- Piste légère --  -- Piste lourde --\n");
    affichage(2,"Test 1");
    affichage(4,"Test 2");

    switch(typeheavy = fork())
    {

        case -1:
            printf("Erreur dans la création processus avion lourd \n");
            break;

        case 0: /* Processus type l'avion lourd */

            printf("test_");
            printf("je suis le fils");
            for (i=0; i<nbAvionsLourd; i++)
            {
                printf("test2_");
                donneesVol-> id = i;
                donneesVol->type = 1;
                donneesVol->destination = 0;

                /*   --- Creation de un thread par avion ---   */
                thr=pthread_create(&avionlourds[i], NULL, Pilote, &donneesVol[i]);
                /*  Erreur de création thread  */

                if (thr)
                {
                    printf("Erreur sur thread %d type avion lourd \n",i);
                }
                for (i=0; i<nbAvionsLourd; i++)
                {
                    pthread_join(avionlourds[i],NULL);
                }

            }

            exit(0);

        default: /* Controleur (poursuit le programme) */

            printf("Dans le default\n");
            wait(0);
            printf("wait passé\n");

    }
    printf("dans le main\n");
    switch(typelight = fork())
    {
        case -1:
            printf("Erreur dans la création processus avion léger \n");
            break;

        case 0: /* Processus fils type l'avion léger */
            for (i=0; i<nbAvionsLeger; i++)
            {
                donneesVol->id = i;
                donneesVol->type = 0;
                donneesVol->destination = 0;

                /*   --- Creation de un thread par avion ---   */
                thr=pthread_create(&avionleger[i], NULL, Pilote, &donneesVol[i]);
                /*  Erreur de création thread  */
                if (thr)
                {
                    printf("Erreur sur thread %d type avion léger \n",i);
                }
                for (i=0; i<nbAvionsLeger; i++)
                {
                    pthread_join(avionleger[i],NULL);
                }
                exit(0);

            }
            break;

        default: /* Controleur (poursuit le programme) */
            wait(0);
            printf("wait passé\n");

    }

    printf("\n  -----        Fin du programme       ----- \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to edit the pthread_create calls to accept that donnesVol is now an array of struct.  Also, using arrays for thread elements is not a good design anyway, but as the OP is doing that anyway, I can hardly use that against you:)  I would have malloced a  new struct in the thread create loop and have the threads free before terminating.

Comment: ...and it probably will if you index '(void *) donneesVol' with 'i' so that each thread gets a pointer to a different struct:)

Comment: I screwed up too - used '@' instead of '&' for address operator.  That's what happens when using several languages:)  I edited my comment.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm beginning programing so that's why a lot of mistakes have been made (I mean I don't have your experience and skills).